# Android Webkit logging full HTML page on keypress

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, webkit

I'm getting very strange logs tagged 'webcore' when trying to input number in textfield.
For example, here is a part of log for key 5 and 6:

```
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):    HTML    0x183440
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):        HEAD    0x1838e0
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):            META    0x1d2d58
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):            META    0x1d0cc8 NAME=viewport
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):            TITLE   0x1ca118
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):                #text   0x1ca460 "Text"
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):            STYLE   0x1ca700
01-26 19:26:31.510: D/webcore(1221):                #text   0x1ca6c0 "\nhtml,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,e {\n  border-collapse:collapse;\n  border-spacing:0\n}\nimg {\n  border-width: 0px;\n}\n"
```

It's some sort of parsed HTML...

And here is a part of log for key 8:

```
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderView at (0,0) size 320x508
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221): layer at (0,0) size 320x0
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderBlock {HTML} at (0,0) size 320x0
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221): layer at (0,40) size 320x418
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderBlock (positioned) zI: 1 {DIV} at (0,40) size 320x418
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221): layer at (0,40) size 320x215
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderBlock (positioned) zI: 1 {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x215
01-26 19:28:54.490: D/webcoreglue(1221):     RenderBlock {SECTION} at (0,0) size 320x215
```

And here is the most interesting thing - application freezing after typing 7:

```
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderView at (0,0) size 320x508
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221): layer at (0,0) size 320x0
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderBlock {HTML} at (0,0) size 320x0
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221): layer at (0,40) size 320x418
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderBlock (positioned) zI: 1 {DIV} at (0,40) size 320x418
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221): layer at (0,40) size 320x215
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):   RenderBlock (positioned) zI: 1 {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x215
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):     RenderBlock {SECTION} at (0,0) size 320x215
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):       RenderBlock {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x215
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):         RenderBlock {DIV} at (0,0) size 320x215
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):           RenderBlock {FORM} at (10,10) size 300x195
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):             RenderBlock (anonymous) at (0,0) size 300x85
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):               RenderTextControl {INPUT} at (0,0) size 300x42 [color=#767677] [bgcolor=#FFFFFF] [border: (1px solid #E4D6BE) none (1px solid #E4D6BE)]
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):               RenderText {#text} at (0,0) size 0x0
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):               RenderTextControl {INPUT} at (0,42) size 300x43 [color=#767677] [bgcolor=#FFFFFF] [border: (1px solid #E4D6BE)]
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):               RenderText {#text} at (0,0) size 0x0
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):             RenderBlock {A} at (95,105) size 110x20
01-26 19:30:31.460: D/webcoreglue(1221):               RenderText {#tex
```

WebView is no longer responds to touch events...

```
01-26 19:33:46.437: W/webview(1221): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I've found a solution - it's because PhoneGap has **webSettings.setNavDump(true)** for some strange reason... And Android WebView listens for key events - if navDump is enabled than it dumps different info...